# Create a matrix from another matrix in Python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I need to create two new numpy.array matrix by using only the odd elements from another matrix for one, and the even elements for the other, and insert zeroes in the positions that aren't even or odd in the respective matrixes. How can I do that?

I tried accessing the indexes of the elements directly but this method doesn't seem to work with arrays.

Example input:

```py
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

should yield two matrixes like:

```
0 2 0          1 0 3
4 0 6    and   0 5 0
0 8 0          7 0 9
```

Comment: please provide a small reproducible example of input/expected output

Comment: Added the example for the problem now

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
is_odd = a%2

odd = np.where(is_odd, a, 0)
even = np.where(1-is_odd, a, 0)
```

output:

```
# odd
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [7, 0, 9]])

# even
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [0, 8, 0]])
```